# vba if digits > num then trim

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need a vba function that will counter the digits for all my column's numbers and if the digits are greater than a 13 let's say ,it would right(trim,9). I can't use the right(trim) alone because there are number with 10 or 11 digits and I have to leave them as they are . this is what i got so far .

```
Function trim(a as String)
    x = Len([numbers])
    If x > 13 Then

        a = Right(trim([numbers]), 9)

    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're not sure how to pass and return parameters.

a is the input parameter, you're supposed to use that instead of `[numbers]`.

Also, it's an exceptionally poor idea to have a conflicting name. `trim` is already used by VBA, choose a different one.

The output parameter's name is just the function name.

Also, you need to declare your variables.

Example:

```
Function TrimLongString(a as String) As String
    Dim x As Long
    x = Len(a)
    If x > 13 Then
        TrimLongString = Right(trim(a), 9)
    Else
        TrimLongString = a
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see any use of this `Dim a As Long`

Comment: I also thought so!